# Prolog Constraint Programing finding even and odd numbers

Tags: prolog, clpfd, constraint-programming

I need to create a predicate:

```
applyConstraints(L)
```

That applies constraints to the variables in L such that no two contiguous elements in L are both odd or even how can I do that? With a fixed size L it's simple but what about a variable size L?
I need that to be done using sicstus-prolog clpfd library.

Comment: can't imagine how could be simpler than a loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by @MatsCarlsson's version, I tried to minimize the number of constrained variables involved:

```
applyConstraints(Xs) :-
   S #\= R,
   applyConstraints(Xs, S, R).

applyConstraints([], _, _).
applyConstraints([X|Xs], S, R) :-
   X mod 2 #= S,
   applyConstraints(Xs, R, S).
```

Edit: This version has one flaw for the goal `applyConstraints([])` which is not readily visible. In fact, one needs to switch to `full_answer` mode in SICStus like so:

```
| ?- applyConstraints([]).
yes
| ?- assertz(clpfd:full_answer).
yes
| ?- applyConstraints([]).
clpfd:(_A#\=_B),
_A in inf..sup,
_B in inf..sup ? ;
no
```

So we have this useless constraint hanging around which might eat up resources.
To overcome this deficiency, some special casing is needed:

```
applyConstraints([]).
applyConstraints([X|Xs]) :-
   X mod 2 #= S,
   S #\= R,
   applyConstraints(Xs, R, S).
```

Note 1 — in <s>SWI or</s> YAP there is no direct way to switch full answer mode on.  The only way to get hold of the problem is to wrap the query around `call_residue_vars/2` like so:

```
?- applyConstraints([]).
true.

?- call_residue_vars(applyConstraints([]),RVs).
RVs = [_G794, _G797],
_G794#\=_G797.
```

Note 2 — Thanks to @mat, there is similar functionality since SWI 7.3 (remember that SWI 7 needs `--traditional` for compatibility):

```
?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_residue_vars, true).
true.

?- applyConstraints([]).
% with detached residual goals
_G430#\=_G433.
```

(It is not quite clear what "detached" should mean in this context, after all, the residual goals *have* to be true, to make the answer true. So there is no detachement involved.)

Comment: With SWI 7.3 or later, you can use `?- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_residue_vars, true).` to see *all* residual constraints.

Answer (score 5):

```
% SICStus:

applyConstraints([]).
applyConstraints([X|Xs]) :-
    X mod 2 #= R,
    applyConstraints(Xs, R).

applyConstraints([], _).
applyConstraints([X|Xs], R) :-
    X mod 2 #= S,
    S #\= R,
    applyConstraints(Xs, S).

% Query:

| ?- applyConstraints(L), length(L,2), !, domain(L,-2,2), labeling([],L).
L = [-2,-1] ? ;
L = [-2,1] ? ;
L = [-1,-2] ? ;
L = [-1,0] ? ;
L = [-1,2] ? ;
L = [0,-1] ? ;
L = [0,1] ? ;
L = [1,-2] ? ;
L = [1,0] ? ;
L = [1,2] ? ;
L = [2,-1] ? ;
L = [2,1] ? ;
no
```

Comment: I think there was no need to throw away your original one-liner solution.  When the OP talks about *variable size L* they probably simply mean *not fixed at compile time*.  You may be giving a bad example here by showing a program with a choicepoint in the constraint setup phase.

Answer (score 1):

Just consider pair of elements

```
applyConstraints([A,B|R]) :-
    A mod 2 #\= B mod 2,
    applyConstraints([B|R]).
applyConstraints([_]).
```

test (using SWI-Prolog library(clpfd), maybe you will need to substitute ins/2 with the counterpart from Sicstus)

```
?- L=[X,Y,Z], applyConstraints(L), L ins 1..4, label(L).
L = [1, 2, 1],
X = Z, Z = 1,
Y = 2 ;
L = [1, 2, 3],
X = 1,
Y = 2,
Z = 3 ;
...
```

Comment: Why don't you write the clauses as is common: Facts first. Your writing induces a bunch of unnecessary overheads.

Comment: @false: because of matching in absence of indexing ?

Comment: Reasons: The absence of indexing (in current implementations), but also the inability to produce answers for the most general query - which is often very useful in the context of diagnosis.

Comment: `applyConstraints([])` fails