# Prolog: Find even numbers add them on a list

Tags: list, prolog, append

Write predicate `evenNumbers(L1, L2)` which is true if the list `L1`
containing random integers and the list `L2` contains even integers from `L1`.

For example:

```
?-evenNumbers ([2,1,-3,6,8,9], L2).
```

»Your program returns `L2 = [2,6,8].`

My code is:

```
    evenNumbers([],[]).
    evenNumbers([H|T],L):-
        integer(H),
        0 is H mod 2,
        append([H],L,L);
        evenNumbers(T,L).
```

Comment: I presume there is something wrong with it, but you haven't explained what.

Comment: the problem is this line: append([H],L,L);
but i dont know how to resolve it without append.

Comment: See the closely related questions [Prolog Constraint Programing finding even and odd numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584521/prolog-constraint-programing-finding-even-and-odd-numbers) and [Sum of even, product of odd numbers in Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543847/sum-of-even-product-of-odd-numbers-in-prolog) and the very nice declarative [**first answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21607900/1613573) and [**second answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32570620/1613573).

Comment: I saw those answers before, but i just started learn prolog.
So it was not so easy to figure out!

Comment: With the solution you accepted, please simply try out the most general query: "*Which solutions are there at all?*" We can ask: `?- evenNumbers(Ls, Es).`, and then we obtain, as the **only** solution: `Ls = Es, Es = []`. Surely that cannot be correct, no? Please think about the properties you actually expect from a Prolog program. For example, in the most general case, it would be terrific if the program answered with a succession of all possible solutions instead of only giving one of them. Let's hope better answers will be posted too. Consider waiting a bit and studying different approaches.

Comment: @mat note that the second answer (using findall) in these cases returns Instantiation error as it should but first one is lacking many properties...

Comment: @coder, throwing an instantiation error is definitely a good improvement over silent failure (silent failure would indicate that there are no further solutions, which would be wrong in this case). However, let us aim higher than this: I think a truly relational solution would be best in this case, which we can use in all directions, also for example if *only* the second, not the first argument is instantiated, and also if *none* of the arguments is instantiated. I think such a solution would most clearly exhibit the logical properties we expect from a declarative program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues  `append([H],L,L);` will stop recursion and give you a wrong list also your if-then-else statement isn't right .So you could write:

```
 evenNumbers([],[]).
 evenNumbers([H|T],L1):-
        integer(H),
        (H mod 2 =:=0 -> L1=[H|T1],evenNumbers(T,T1);
        evenNumbers(T,L1) ).
```

Example:

```
?- evenNumbers([2,1,-3,6,8,9], L2).
L2 = [2, 6, 8].
```

Another way writing it would be:

```
evenNumbers(L1,L2):-findall(X,(member(X,L1), X mod 2=:=0),L2).
```