# Prolog - Finding even elements in a list

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I want to write a rule in Prolog that returns the even elements in a given list. For example:
even_elements([1,2,3,4], Result) would return Result: [2,4]

Here is what I have so far:

```
% This is my base case.
even_elements([H|T], Result) :- (0 is mod(H,2) -> Result = [H|T] ; Result = T). 

% This is my recursion.
even_elements([H|T], [H|NT]) :- even_elements(T, NT).
```

The base case works properly and eliminates the first element if it is odd; but the recursion doesn't change anything. Any tips on how to complete the recursion is appreciated.

Comment: The base case does not look like a base case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often the base case in list processing deals with the *empty* list. Indeed, we can just write:

```
even_elements([], []).
```

For the recursive case, we can use quite a lot from your base case, the only thin that we still need to do is *recurse* on the *tail* of the list, so:

```
even_elements([H|T], Result) :-
    (  0 is mod(H,2)
    -> Result = [H|T2]
    ;  Result = T2
    ),
    even_elements(T, T2).
```

That being said, there is no need to implement the logic to filter a list. You can make use of the [**`include/3`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=include/3), and thus define an `even` predicate:

```
even(N) :-
    0 is N mod 2.
```

Then we can filter with:

```
even_elements(L, R) :-
    include(even, L, R).
```

This then gives us:

```
?- even_elements([1,4,2,5], R).
R = [4, 2].
```

Answer (score 1):

I also found this solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40566662/prolog-find-even-numbers-add-them-on-a-list) although Willem's answer is way more readable:

```
even_elements(L1,L2):-findall(X,(member(X,L1), X mod 2=:=0),L2).
```